# How to optimize min/max queries for large tables on PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

How do you index a table in PostgreSQL so that min/max queries return as quickly as possible?

I have a large table with a couple hundred million rows. Each row as a source_id and a date when the record was last updated. I'd like to collect some statistics for each source_id, specifically the min and max date range for each source_id.

So I created this index on my table:

```
 CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY mydata_source_last_updated_date ON mydata (source_id, last_updated_date ASC);
```

However, when I try to query the min dates per source with:

```
SELECT source_id, MIN(last_updated_date) FROM mydata GROUP BY source_id;
```

the query takes about an hour to complete.

Is this normal performance for such a large table, even with an index? How can I reduce this query time?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info - please add the execution plan, PostgreSQL version, OS, HW specs at least.

Comment: How many distinct values of source_id are there, relative to the number of rows in the table?

Comment: @jjanes, A couple dozen.

Answer (score 5):

With only a few dozen distinct values of source_id, you can get fast execution on the index you built, using a [loose index scan, aka a "skip scan"](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Loose_indexscan).  Unfortunately PostgreSQL does not plan those automatically, so you have to force it into one, by using a recursive query.

```
with recursive t as ( 
   select min(source_id) as col from mydata 
   union all 
   select (select min(source_id) from mydata where source_id>t.col)
      from t where t.col is not null) 
select 
  col, 
  (select min(last_updated_date) from mydata where source_id=col),
  (select max(last_updated_date) from mydata where source_id=col)
  from t;
```

Even if you don't resort to this, just doing the query as you originally wrote it should not take nearly an hour.  But without seeing an `explain` and an `explain analyze`, there isn't much more that can be said on that.